# Usage de "bon mois"

Tags: usage, salutations

Debut du mois aujourd'hui et j'ai voulu souhaiter (inspiré, bien sûr, de ma [langue maternelle](https://lavieencrete.com/kalo-mina/)) : "bon mois". On m'a dit que ça ne se dit pas. Y a-t-il une raison particulière ?

Comment: Il te reste quand même au moins: bonne journée, bon après-midi, bonne soirée, bonne nuit, bonne semaine et bon week-end ;-)

Comment: Et Bonne Année! Par contre, je ne suis pas sure si "bon Carême" s'utilise très souvent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cela n'est pas d'usage.

Si je devais tenter une explication, je dirais que la transition d'un mois à l'autre n'apporte aucun changement particulier.
Notre mode de vie est en effet rythmé par une périodicité quotidienne, hebdomadaire et annuelle, mais pas mensuelle (hormis pour certains éléments, principalement le salaire et les factures).

Answer (score 4):

Je n'ai jamais entendu cette expression en français (juste "bon mois"), quoique j'imagine qu'on pourrait dire :

> Je vous souhaite un bon mois (d'avril), plein d'accomplissements.

J'ai aussi rencontré l'expression :

> passez un (très) bon mois de février !

Aussi, on peut souhaiter un bon mois qui reçoit un nom particulier de par les activités qui se passent pendant ce mois :

> BON MOIS DE LA FRANCOPHONIE! ([source](https://connect2canada.com/2020/03/bon-mois-de-la-francophonie/))

Answer (score 1):

Le seul exemple de cette expression, *bon mois*,  qui me vienne est une chanson médiévale de Guillaume Dufay: *Bon jour, bon mois, bon an et bonne estraine* ([partition en PDF](https://www.moyenagepassion.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/musique_chanson_medievale_guillaume_dufay_moyen-age_tardif_rondeau_XVe.pdf)).

Il semble que depuis ce temps son usage s'est perdu.